# Constant Variance Assumption in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, diagnostic

It seems to me that the following plot of "Residuals Vs. Fitted Values" violates the assumption of constant variance, since for lower fitted values, there are fewer points whereas for higher fitted values, there are dense points. [image]

Am I correctly interpreting the plot?

Comment: I don't think there is hetereogeneity here, you have a lot more points on the right so it gives a false impression.

Answer (score 3):

The non-constant variance is related to the spread of the points along the y axis. So if there's a funnel shape, for example, we would say: "as the fitted values increases, the variance of the residual (along the y axis) increases too".
Look the image below. The x axis represents the fitted values, and the y axis represents the residuals.
The third one is the only with constant variance.

[image: residuals plots]

Comment: These funnel shapes can sometimes be difficult to observe when the density along the x-axis is not the same. For instance a plot of two independent normal distributed variables $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ may have conditional distributions with constant variance, but in a plot it looks like a circular shape and the middle part looks more bulky/wide than the outer edges.

Answer (score 0):

residual plot telling you about the model fitting . what you have assumed for the model , as if you assumed the pure white noise model constant mean, constant variance, . this plot shows yes model is good fitted for the particular case, however some departure around the mean lines but these are being adjusted at the end . further expertise can judge more the behavior . i guessed it is ok no heterogeneity